# jquery function to detect if href of thumbnail matches src of full-size image?

Tags: jquery

I have a thumbnail grid, with a full size image next to the grid.

```
 <div id="gallery-thumbs"> 
    <ul class="thumb"> 
    <li><a href="images/medium.jpg"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" /></a></li> 
    </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="main-view"> 
 <img src="images/medium.jpg" /> 
 </div>
```

I want to set up a jquery function that detects if the "href" attribute of ul.thumb li a, matches the src attribute of #main-view img.

And if does indeed match, change the opacity of the thumbnail image to 100%.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mainViewURL = $("#main-view img").attr("src");
var thumbs = $("#gallery-thumbs .thumb li a");
$.each(thumbs, function(){
    if(mainViewURL == $(this).attr("href")){
        $("img", this).animate({ opacity: 1.0 }); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_opacity() {
 if ($('ul#thumb li a').attr('href') == $('div#main-view img').attr('src')) {
    $('ul#thumb li img').css('opacity','0.4');
  }
}
```

hope this will help you.
You can even assign $('ul#thumb li') to some variable like var thumb = $('ul#thumb li').

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in the form of a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.fullSizeFullOpacity = function () {
  return this.each(function () {
    var $a = $(this).find('a'),
        $img = $a.find('img');
    if ($a.attr('href') == $img.attr('src')) {
      $img.css('opacity', 1.0);
    }
  });
};

$('.thumb li').fullSizeFullOpacity ();
```

Here is a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-full-size-full-opacity) test where I played with different versions to see performance.